# Node Lambda Function can't query an AWS Aurora MySQL database

Tags: mysql, node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, aws-aurora-serverless

I'm trying to write to an aws aurora mysql database with a Lambda Function.

#### Code

For some reason, it doesn't seem to work. Until this point, my code is very simple but fails to execute correctly. It is a simple lambda function, that is called when a user signs up to cognito and should just create a new entry in the SQL db with user credentials.

```
const mysql = require('mysql')

const db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "*****",
    port: *****,
    user: "*****",
    password: "*****",
    database: "*****",
})

export const lambdaHandler = async (event: any, context: any,) => {
    const user = {
        uid: event.request.userAttributes.sub,
        username: event.request.userAttributes.nickname,
        email: event.request.userAttributes.email,
    }

    console.log("before query")

    const query = `INSERT INTO users (Uid, Username, Email) VALUES (${user.uid}, ${user.username}, ${user.email})`
    await db.query(query, (err: any, result: any) => {
        if (err) console.error(err)

        console.log("query response: " + result)
    })

    console.log("after query")

    return event;
};
```

The output of the function is the following:

```
START RequestId: bb1d2143-97e4-4761-a48a-f482cf94f73b Version: $LATEST
2022-03-17T14:02:35.956Z        bb1d2143-97e4-4761-a48a-f482cf94f73b    INFO    before query
2022-03-17T14:02:35.961Z        bb1d2143-97e4-4761-a48a-f482cf94f73b    INFO    after query
END RequestId: bb1d2143-97e4-4761-a48a-f482cf94f73b
REPORT RequestId: bb1d2143-97e4-4761-a48a-f482cf94f73b  Init Duration: 0.14 ms  Duration: 138.07 ms     Billed Duration: 139 ms Memory Size: 128 MB     Max Memory Used: 128 MB
```

Note: there is no log to be found by the query function. (should either throw error or log response)

#### Policies

The policies that are in the execution Role of the lambda function are: `AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole` and `AWSLambda_FullAccess`

#### Other

The Lambda function and Aurora are in different subnets of the same vpc. I am not sure if this could result in a problem. But wouldn't that lead to an error thrown by the function? Something like `missing authorization`?

I don't understand what else I'm missing at this point

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that `db.query` uses the callback-style instead of promise-style. You have to convert it to use promises.

One way of doing it is using [`Util.promisify`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#utilpromisifyoriginal)...

```
const util = require('util');
const mysql = require('mysql');

const db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "*****",
    port: *****,
    user: "*****",
    password: "*****",
    database: "*****",
});

// Convert db.query into a function that returns a promise
const promisifiedQuery = util.promisify(db.query);

export const lambdaHandler = async (event: any, context: any,) => {
    const user = {
        uid: event.request.userAttributes.sub,
        username: event.request.userAttributes.nickname,
        email: event.request.userAttributes.email,
    };

    console.log("before query");

    // BTW, this is bad. Read about how to avoid SQL injections.
    const query = `INSERT INTO users (Uid, Username, Email) VALUES (${user.uid}, ${user.username}, ${user.email})`;

    await promisifiedQuery(query).then(result => {
        console.log("query response: " + result)
        console.log("after query")
    }).catch(console.error)

    return event;
};
```

Comment: Hey thank you for your answer I will try it out as soon as I have time. About the SQL infections: how would someone inject something there if this runs on a Node backend server? Also the Function is triggered by the AWS Cognito Authentication service. So I am not really sure how you would inject something there. Thank you!!

Comment: I don't have an example but a malicious user can sign up with some malicious SQL as the username.

Comment: As a general rule, it's better not to underestimate malicious users. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `db.connect()` before doing the query and `db.end()` after you did the query. See https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#introduction. I suspect if you don't it just ignores the `await db.query`

Comment: In my understanding of the documentation the .query() runs .connect() automatically if it wasn't called previously. I have tried it with .connect() but I still don't see a response